# Prove or disprove that : $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-x^{2}}\right)!-1-\frac{1}{e^{x^{2}}+1}\right)dx+\frac{7}{10}<0$

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, improper-integrals, approximation, gamma-function

Prove or disprove that :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-x^{2}}\right)!-1-\frac{1}{e^{x^{2}}+1}\right)dx+\frac{7}{10}<0$$

---

---

It's an experiment using Desmos .

Some facts :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^{x^{2}}+1}\right)dx=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)\sqrt{\pi}\zeta{(\frac{1}{2})}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-x^{2}}\right)!-1\right)dx<-\frac{164}{100}\quad(1)$$

First I have tried to show $(1)$ using elementary method as integrations by parts but it goes nowhere.*To go further I use the Stirling approximation modified (Ramanujan) on $(1,\infty)$ and then use power series but it seems delicate *.On the other hand I don't see a good substitution to tackle it .

*Oups I was working on other integral..This part is not relevant.

---

---

---

Question :

Can we hope to show it by hand or it is illusory ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I guess your brain goes fast as a computer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Some thoughts**:

We need to prove that
$$\int_0^\infty \left(1 - \Gamma(1 + x^{3/2}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2})\right) \mathrm{d} x > \frac{7}{10} + \frac{\sqrt2 - 1}{2}\zeta(\tfrac12)\sqrt{\pi}.$$

For a function $f(x)$, let $T(f(x),a,n)$ denote the $n$-th order Taylor approximation of $f(x)$ at $x = a$.

*Fact 1*: $0 \le x^{3/2}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2} < 2/5$ for all $x\ge 0$.

*Fact 2*: For all $y\in [0, 2/5)$,
$$\Gamma(1 + y) \le T(\Gamma(1 + y), 0, 10).$$
(The proof of Fact 2 is given at then end.)

Using Facts 1-2, it suffices to prove that
$$\int_0^\infty \left(1 - T(\Gamma(1 + y), 0, 10)\Big\vert_{y = x^{3/2}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}}\right) \mathrm{d} x > \frac{7}{10} + \frac{\sqrt2 - 1}{2}\zeta(\tfrac12)\sqrt{\pi}$$
which is true.
*Note*: Here the integral admits a closed form in terms of
$\gamma, \zeta(3), \zeta(5), \zeta(7), \zeta(9), \zeta(1/2), \Gamma(3/4)$ etc.

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

We use the Taylor series of $\ln \Gamma(1 + y)$:
$$\ln \Gamma(1 + y) = - \gamma y + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(k)}{k}(-1)^k y^k, \quad |y| < 1.$$
We have, for all $y\in [0, 2/5)$,
$$\ln \Gamma(1 + y) \le 
- \gamma y + \sum_{k=2}^{10} \frac{\zeta(k)}{k}(-1)^k y^k.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$- \gamma y + \sum_{k=2}^{10} \frac{\zeta(k)}{k}(-1)^k y^k
\le \ln \Big[T(\Gamma(1 + y), 0, 10)\Big].$$
Let $F(y) = \mathrm{RHS} - \mathrm{LHS}$.
We have $F(0) = 0$.
One can prove that
$F'(y) \ge 0$ for all $y\in [0, 2/5)$.

We are done.

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: @RounakSarkar $f(x)$ refers to a non-specific function. In other words, you input a function $f(x)$, $T(f(x), a, n)$ gives a Taylor approximation. For example, if $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$, then $T(\mathrm{e}^x,0, 2) = 1 + x + x^2/2$. If $f(x) = W(x)$, then $T(f(x), 0, 2) = x - x^2$ where $W(x)$ is the principal branch of the Lambert W function.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Thanks for comment. I edited it a little bit.

Comment: It's ok, I actually didn't read your answer carefully, that's why I made that stupid comment.

Comment: Your conjecture is interesting. It seems that the Taylor polynomials are enveloping $\Gamma(1+x)$ on $(0,1)$. I was not able to find a proof of this fact in the literature.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for comment. I am not sure if it is true. Perhaps an estimate of the error bound is easier and enough.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. Thanks for providing it. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks.